# Convert Google Earth Engine images to histograms without downloading them first

Tags: google-earth, google-earth-engine

I want to download a large collection of MODIS satellite data. The problem is that the data will be upwards of 200GB and this is not feasible for me to download. So I want to access the images and convert them to histogram of pixel counts instead without having to download the images. This way I only store the histogram representation of the images.

How can I access the images and convert them on the fly without having to export them to Google Drive or Google Cloud?

Comment: Do you want to export the histogram for each MODIS dataset? What are you planning to do with those histograms? Maybe you can perform more of your calculation on GEE and in the end just have to export a small result.

Comment: I want to use the histograms as input for a CNN in tensorflow since it is not feasible for me to download the massive amount of satellite images I need.

Comment: And then train a CNN on a per-image-basis? What are you attempting to achieve with that? If you are set on training a CNN based on histrograms why not download them on more meaningful spatial areas - such as a polygons based on expected land cover, a previous classification or even a smaller grid than MODIS 2km swath.